# Suspending programs running under a certain user

Tags: security, sandbox

I am isolating less trusted programs that need access to x (such as web browsers) with this method.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Simple_sandbox

But any program that has access to my x session can log all keys from that
session by doing `xinput test <keyboard-id>`.  This is usually an acceptable
risk provided the isolated programs are not *that* likely to be compromised.
But, when typing passwords, I would like to make it impossible for them to
listen in.  Two simple ways of doing this would be (i) shutting them down and
(ii) typing passwords in a different tty.  But that's a bit inconvenient.  As
far as I can see, *suspending every program run by unprivileged
users* would be preferable.  Is there a shell command that will suspend every
program running under the user bob?

Comment: IIUC if you would X11 tunnel it via SSH it won't have access to your X11 session to be able to do anything.

Comment: @JiriB, I'm doing this to a web browser, so it needs access to x.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pkill -u bob -STOP
```

to suspend and

```
sudo pkill -u bob -CONT
```

to resume.